# PyQt5 Threading - RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt, pyqt5

Looking to thread my app. Below is a portion of the code. From my understanding, I need to emit a signal from my thread class, and in my Main class, I start the thread. I just want to be able to move the window around and not lose functionality while the final_button action is taking place. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: based on eyllanesc's feedback, changed my code to be an `if` statement rather than a `while True` statement. The problem still persists - once I press the final button, the app loses control. The window can't be moved and the title bar shows Not Responding until the final button actions finish. I'm wondering if I can adjust my code below to fix the issue. Thanks.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFileDialog, QMessageBox
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal
from config_assign_ui import Ui_ConfigAssign
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd

class Main(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_ConfigAssign):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.thread = Thread()
        self.thread.start()
        self.thread.final_button.connect(self.final_button)
        self.combo_list()
        self.ImportMapButton.clicked.connect(self.import_map)
        self.ExceptButton.clicked.connect(self.except_file)
        self.FinalButton.clicked.connect(self.final_button)

    def combo_list(self):
        # do a SQL query to show a list of customer options

    def import_map(self, df_map):
        name = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Open Map...", "T:/Drive",
                                        "Worksheets (*.xlsx;*.xlsm;*.xlsb;*.xls)")
        file = str(name[0])
        if file != '':
            while True:
                try:
                    xl = pd.ExcelFile(file)
                    self.df_map = xl.parse('Sheet1')
                    rows = self.df_map.shape[0]
                    rows = "{:,}".format(rows)
                    self.labelMapCount.setText(rows)
                except:
                    mb = QMessageBox()
                    mb.setWindowTitle('Problem with File')
                    mb.setText("Please try again")
                    mb.setStyleSheet("QLabel{min-width:180 px}")
                    mb.exec_()
                    break
                # check columns of file
                cols = ['CategoryId','CategoryName','SubcategoryId','SubcategoryName','MakeId','MakeName']
                cols_file = list(self.df_map)
                if cols_file != cols:
                    mb = QMessageBox()
                    mb.setWindowTitle('Column Error')
                    mb.setText('Columns names do not match template')
                    mb.setStyleSheet('QLabel{min-width:220 px}')
                    mb.exec_()
                    break
                else:
                    break

    def except_file(self, df_except):
        if self.ExceptCheckBox.isChecked():
            # do some processing of an exception file that the user can import

    def final_button(self):
        # check if df_map exists
        try:
            print(self.df_map.head())
            map_avail = 1
        except AttributeError:
            mb = QMessageBox()
            mb.setWindowTitle('Map Missing')
            mb.setText('Please import map first')
            mb.setStyleSheet("QLabel{min-width:200 px}")
            mb.exec_()
            map_avail = 0

        if map_avail == 1:
        #perform a bunch of actions


class Thread(QtCore.QThread):
    final_button = pyqtSignal()
    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        while True:
            time.sleep(2)
            self.final_button.emit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Main()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: You have explained your possible solution, but you have not explained your background problem, that is called [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/), Also why is a thread necessary since I do not see you executing a heavy task on that thread?

Comment: In the final_button, there are SQL queries that take some time to run and a few other calculations and things that will take additional time. It's not a lot of time, but I'd rather not have the whole program say Not Responding and be unmovable and unclickable.

Comment: It may be generating problems in `while True:` in a GUI you should not use it since they block the GUI

Comment: Ok got it. I will think of different logic than while True and try that out.

Comment: Adjusted code above, but problem persists. Any help with the threading issue?

Comment: I recommend learning to test, for example using the old school: comment what you think the problem may bring, execute your code and if there are no problems then uncomment another section and have the previous analysis, if it does not work then comment another part to know in which line is the error. Also if you want help improve your MCVE for example: Are the import_map and except_file part relevant ?, is it necessary to import pyodbc ?, etc.